# Why does the limit of a subsequence lie in a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading through a proof where I encountered the following:

> Let $K_0\subset K$, where $K$ is a compact metric space, and $K_0$ is closed.
>
> If $x_{n}\subset K$ has a convergent subsequence, then the limit of the subsequence lies in $K_0$.

My question is why does it necessarily have to lie in $K_0$? Why does $K_0$ being closed force the limit of the subsequence to lie in $K_0$? Why can't the limit of the subsequence lie in $K$?

I think it has something to do with the fact that a closed set contains all its limit points, but I'm not sure exactly why. Any clarification for this confusion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I don't think this is true as stated : consider $K := [-2,2], K_0 := [-1,1]$ and $x_n := 2-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Indeed. Possibly a typo in the proof? They meant to say "If $x_n \subset K_0$"?